# How to return many to many relations values as json format (not just the ids)?

Tags: django, json, generics, many-to-many

I have a model with ManyToManyField to another model. I would like to get all the info on a particular record (including the related info from other models) return by JSON.

Before posting my question I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049519/django-piston-how-to-get-values-of-a-many-to-many-field) but its not the same I'm looking for. I'm not using piston.

**models.py**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description


class Practice(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    main_subject = models.ForeignKey(to=Subject)
    related_subjects = models.ManyToManyField(to=Subject, related_name="practices")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.title)
```

I implemented a generic list view that returns a list of **Practice** instances in json format ...

**listviews.py**

```
class PracticeListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Practice.objects.all()


class PracticeListViewJSON(PracticeListView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    data = json_serializer.serialize(queryset, ensure_ascii=False)        
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

But the json data doesn't brings the **Subject** description values, but just its references as ids.

**json**

[{"pk": 1, "model": "app.pratice", "fields": {"related_subjects": [2, 4]}}]

What should I do to have a return like this

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "app.pratice", 
           "fields": {"related_subjects": ["model": "app.subject", 
                                                    "fields": {"description": "description of the subject #1"}, 
                                           "model": "app.subject", 
                                                    "fields": {"description": "description of the subject #2"},
                                                    ...
]
```

Comment: Serching for the solution I found something useful to those (like me) are dealing with UTF8 data in the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/#id2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753359/serializing-foreign-key-objects-in-django

Comment: some trouble with utf-8 can be soved looking http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/issues/detail?id=19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding duplicate keys to JSON with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519858/adding-duplicate-keys-to-json-with-python)