# Adding duplicate keys to JSON with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Is there a way to add duplicate keys to json with python?

From my understanding, you can't have duplicate keys in python dictionaries. Usually, how I go about creating json is to create the dictionary and then `json.dumps`. However, I need duplicated keys within the JSON for testing purposes. But I can't do so because I can't add duplicate keys in a python dictionary. I am trying to doing this in python 3

Comment: @DonkeyKong unfortunately not...

Comment: Cannot have duplicate keys in dictionary. Cannot have duplicate keys in json.

Comment: Can have duplicate keys in JSON the fileformat.

Comment: Duplicate keys in JSON is not interoperable, as stated in the RFC: An object whose names are all unique is interoperable. However, you can write your own JSON encoder/decoder in Python such that a dict with multiple values in a list is collapsed into multiple k:v pairs

Comment: @taesu you can have duplicate keys in JSON

Comment: actually you can, as long as your keys are different (different hashes for the dict) but have the same str (same key for json.dump). One example is using ints and strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always construct such a string value by hand.

On the other hand, one can make the **C**Python `json` module to encode duplicate keys. This is **very** tricky in **Python 2** because `json` module does not respect duck-typing at all.

The straightforward solution would be to inherit from `collections.Mapping` - well you can't, since *"`MyMapping` is not a JSON serializable."*

Next one tries to subclass a `dict` - well, but if `json.dumps` notices that the type is `dict`, it skips from calling `__len__`, and sees the underlying `dict` directly - if it is empty, `{}` is output directly, so clearly if we fake the methods, the underlying dictionary must not be empty.

The next source of joy is that actually `__iter__` is called, which iterates keys; and for each key, the `__getitem__` is called, so we need to remember what is the corresponding value to return for the given key... thus we arrive to a very ugly solution for Python 2:

```
class FakeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, items):
        # need to have something in the dictionary
        self['something'] = 'something'
        self._items = items

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.last_val

    def __iter__(self):
        def generator():
            for key, value in self._items:
                self.last_val = value
                yield key

        return generator()
```

---

In CPython 3.3+ it is slightly easier... no, `collections.abc.Mapping` does not work, yes, you need to subclass a `dict`, yes, you need to fake that your dictionary has content... but the internal JSON encoder calls `items` instead of `__iter__` and `__getitem__`!

Thus on Python 3:

```
import json

class FakeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, items):
        self['something'] = 'something'
        self._items = items
    def items(self):
        return self._items

print(json.dumps(FakeDict([('a', 1), ('a', 2)])))
```

prints out

```
{"a": 1, "a": 2}
```

Comment: Hmm running this code in my interpreter and I am getting `'{}'`

Comment: Hem, forgot to add the faked contents to Python 3 version

Comment: its not working .it just printing {'something':'something'}

Comment: @VennilaM what, where?

Comment: Works like a charm. It can be used as simply as `obj = json.loads(data, object_pairs_hook=FakeDict)` and then `json.dumps(obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot Antti Haapala, I figured out you can even use this to convert an array of tuples into a FakeDict:

```
def function():
    array_of_tuples = []
    array_of_tuples.append(("key","value1"))
    array_of_tuples.append(("key","value2"))
    return FakeDict(array_of_tuples)

print(json.dumps(function()))
```

Output:

```
{"key": "value1", "key": "value2"}
```

And if you change the FakeDict class to this Empty dictionaries will be correctly parsed:

```
class FakeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, items):
        if items != []:
            self['something'] = 'something'
        self._items = items
    def items(self):
        return self._items
def test():
    array_of_tuples = []
    return FakeDict(array_of_tuples)

print(json.dumps(test()))
```

Output:

```
"{}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's very easy:

```
$> python -c "import json; print json.dumps({1: 'a', '1': 'b'})"
{"1": "b", "1": "a"}
```

Comment: This will only work directly in very limited circumstances. The underlying idea is to have multiple distinct objects with the same string representation.