# python3 dictionary with duplicate keys but different values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests

I need to submit a formdata which looks like this :

```
evt: 2001
evt: 1024001
src: mstrWeb.my.fbb.fb.2001
src: mstrWeb.my.fbb.1024001
```

When I create a python3 `dict` :

```
Dict = {'evt': '2001',
    'evt': '1024001',
    'src': 'mstrWeb.my.fbb.fb.2001',
    'src': 'mstrWeb.my.fbb.1024001'}
```

it removes the duplicate keys by order. I get:

```
>>> print (Dict)
{'evt': '1024001', 'src': 'mstrWeb.my.fbb.1024001'}
```

Is there any way I can have the duplicate keys intact in my Dict ?

Comment: Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. Can't you have a list of all the values associated with the "evt" key?

Comment: @Carcigenicate ,its basically a formdata i need to submit using requests.post to a URL . Unfortunately the values can't be in a list

Comment: Why can't they? You can't have duplicate keys, so you'll need to look for a different way. To get better suggestions, you might need to hive more context to explain why the value can't be a list, since that's the simple work around.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, the host URL i am making the POST request does not accept values in a list for same key

Comment: But you can just take the values out of the list before submitting the request. If you're submitting it as a JSON, you can't have duplicate keys anyways either.

Comment: I found this link , that says instantiating an class object : http://www.wellho.net/mouth/3934_Multiple-identical-keys-in-a-Python-dict-yes-you-can-.html

But it returns an object not string. when i add a function to return string , python just removes it

Comment: They're abusing the hashes returned from objects to add multiple of the same key. They're just wrapping the string in another object, making it so it's simulating identical keys, even though the keys are on fact different. I can't say this is recommended by any means.

Comment: This actually worked for my purpose : http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=y107/wp2

Comment: @ShekharSamanta, if you have a solution that works for you, please do write it up as an answer so that other users can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Python dicts have unique keys.  There is no getting around that.

One  approach might be to make a `defaultdict` of lists in Python followed by jinga `for` loops in the form code to iterate the values of the dict.

Alternatively, if you are able to send a `json` string, [this workaround for handling duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519858/adding-duplicate-keys-to-json-with-python) may help:

**Given**

```
data = [
    ("evt", "2001"),
    ("evt", "1024001"),
    ("src", "mstrWeb.my.fbb.fb.2001"),
    ("src", "mstrWeb.my.fbb.1024001")
]
```

**Code**

```
class Container(dict):
    """Overload the items method to retain duplicate keys."""

    def __init__(self, items):
        self[""] = ""
        self._items = items

    def items(self):
        return self._items


json.dumps(Container(data))
# '{"evt": "2001", "evt": "1024001", "src": "mstrWeb.my.fbb.fb.2001", "src": "mstrWeb.my.fbb.1024001"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, I took it from here : [Link](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/3934_Multiple-identical-keys-in-a-Python-dict-yes-you-can-.html)

```
class person(object):
        def __init__(self,name):
                self.name = name

        # As it would print for a user
        def __str__(self):
                return self.name

        # As it would print for a debugging person
        def __repr__(self):
                return "'"+self.name+"'"


Dict = {person('evt'): '2001',
        person('evt'): '1024001',
        person('src'): 'mstrWeb.my.fbb.fb.2001',
        person('src'): 'mstrWeb.my.fbb.1024001'}

print (Dict) #outputs

{'evt': '2001', 'evt': '1024001', 'src': 'mstrWeb.my.fbb.fb.2001', 'src': 'mstrWeb.my.fbb.1024001'}
```