# Constructing JSON using Python Dictionary but with duplicate key name

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

What I want is to make a JSON that looks like this.

```
{
    "filelist": [
        {
            "filename": "file1.txt",
            "oof": 0
        },
        {
            "filename": "file2.txt",
            "oof": 0
        },
        {
            "filename": "file3.txt",
            "oof": 0
        }
    ]
    
}
```

What I did was:

```
for line in listoflines:
    mysmalldict ["filename"] = line.strip("\n")
    mysmalldict ["oof"] = 0
    dictcollector.append(mysmalldict)

mybigdict[filelist"] = dictcollector
print(json.dumps(mybigdict))
```

Unfortunately, What I got was:

```
{
    "filelist": [
        {
            "filename": "file3.txt",
            "oof": 0
        },
        {
            "filename": "file3.txt",
            "oof": 0
        },
        {
            "filename": "file3.txt",
            "oof": 0
        }
    ]
    
}
```

Everything was overwritten by the last data.

After a couple of searches, I learned that Python dictionaries will overwrite data of the same keys.
Some examples I found like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/how-can-one-make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python) one doesn't fit my need as I need a duplicate key pair and not multiple values on one key.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519858/adding-duplicate-keys-to-json-with-python) one that is close but when I put the FakeDict on my dictcollector, it gives a different structure.

```
{
    "filelist": [
        '{
            "filename": "file3.txt",
            "oof": 0
        }',
        '{
            "filename": "file3.txt",
            "oof": 0
        }',
        '{
            "filename": "file3.txt",
            "oof": 0
        }'
    ]
    
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Python? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Thing is that dicts are passed by reference and whenever you change something in your dict it will be changed wherever you already passed it by reference. To solve it, you can append new dict in every iteration of for loop, like this: `dictcollector.append({"filename": line ...})`.

Comment: `dictcollector.append(mysmalldict)` This is your problem.  You are not appending a _copy_ of the dictionary as it exists in that moment -- you are appending the _actual live dictionary object_.  (If it helps, you can think of this as a _reference_ to the dictionary.)  So when you update the dict with a new "filename" key in the next loop, you're also updating all the dicts that you previously appended to the list, because they are all the _same object_.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic so, this terminology is commonly used incorrectly, but nothing in Python is ever pass by reference, and the evaluation strategy doesn't depend on the type of object involved (there is only one evaluation strategy that is neither call by reference nor call by value)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new dictionary on every iteration:

```
for line in listoflines:
    mysmalldict = {} # add this
    mysmalldict["filename"] = line.strip("\n")
    mysmalldict["oof"] = 0
    dictcollector.append(mysmalldict)

mybigdict["filelist"] = dictcollector
print(json.dumps(mybigdict))
```

In your example, you have created `mysmalldict` outside the loop and assigned it 3 times to `dictcollector`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the dict, just append it as a whole.

Instead of

```
dictcollector.append(mysmalldict)
```

use

```
dictcollector.append({"key":"pair","key":"pair"})
```